# SharePoint, throwing Exception after impersonation

Tags: sharepoint

We are impersonating a SharePoint User  and trying to acces a list item.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(BAH.SN.Properties.Settings.Default.RootSiteUrl, new SPUserToken(currentUser.ImpersonationToken)))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPList list = web.GetList(BAH.SN.Properties.Settings.Default.CommunitiesListPath);
                if (list != null)
                {
                    SPQuery query = CAMLHelper.GetSPQueryForCommunityListByOwner(user.UserName);
                    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
                    if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // Read here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

We are able to get a handle on the list, but as soon as we try to access any property of SPListItemCollection "items", we get a COM exception: 532459699.

We are running FBA and the user calling this code is an anonymous user.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ElevatedPrivileges` instead of a token?

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() { 
    //your code inside here, except use the SPSite ctor that only takes the url and get that frome SPContext:
    // new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url);
}
```

Also please provide full stack trace to give us the best way to help you.
If you don't know how to enable that in `web.config`, check one of the many blog posts on that issue [here](http://blogs.importchaos.com/alonsorobles/2008/06/09/enabling-the-sharepoint-safe-mode-call-stack-disabling-custom-errors-and-enabling-compilation-debugging/).

Answer (score 0):

`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` will run the code in the System Account. That wont solve his/her issue.