# SharePoint WebPart Impersonation problem

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2007, web-parts, impersonation

I want to render all WebParts on the Page in context of some other user which password is unknown. I'm SiteCollection Administrator. 
Solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591433/sharepoint-throwing-exception-after-impersonation)

does not do the trick because there are some webparts like ListViewWebPart i can't modify and I can't inherit.

Best solution would be to write webPart which will modify context of all others, however I'm not sure how to ensure that webPart is rendered as first and how to modify the context.

Do you think that global.asax might be useful in this situation?

Regards

Adam

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as a whole ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the user context available, and you don't know their password, how could you impersonate them? Being an administrator doesn't give you the power to trump the underlying security model or audit trail.

Comment: normally you can impersonate the code, creating SPSite with proper userToken without knowledge about password of the user (see link I've pasted above). The problem is that I do not have access to code of for example ListViewWebPart so I can't change its context

Comment: @Adam you cannot impersonate any arbitrary user - you can only impersonate a user who has an active context in SharePoint. The code example you linked to is impersonating the currently logged-in user.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the only way I could think of is modifying the compat.browser file so any call to the OOTB ListViewWebPart would be redirected to your own, derived CustomListViewWebPart. Still not sure if tyhat will do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is ListViewWebPart is sealed (as half of sharePoint classes :/)